# Using @SVGR/cli with a template example is throwing `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, templates, import, babeljs

I'm using [SVGR's CLI tool](https://react-svgr.com/docs/options/#template) to try to create a template for a [MUI](https://mui.com)-compatible React icon that works with Next. Per their docs:

```
Template

Specify a template file (CLI) or a template function (API) to use. For an example of template, see the default one.

Default CLI Override                API Override
basic template         --template   template: <func>
```

You can see they point to the project's [defaultTemplate.ts](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/blob/main/packages/babel-plugin-transform-svg-component/src/defaultTemplate.ts) file, which looks like this:

```tsx
import type { Template } from './types'

export const defaultTemplate: Template = (variables, { tpl }) => {
  return tpl`
${variables.imports};
${variables.interfaces};
const ${variables.componentName} = (${variables.props}) => (
  ${variables.jsx}
);
 
${variables.exports};
`
}
```

I've tried to lay out a quick yarn project that looks like this:

#### /

```
package.json
```

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^5.68.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx @svgr/cli --typescript --memo --svg-props preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' --template ./template --out-dir dist -- icons"
  }
}
```

#### template/

```
mui.template.ts
```

(Same as the default template)

```
package.json
```

```json
{
  "name": "mui.template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "description": "MUI icon template for SVGR",
  "main": "mui.template.ts",
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

But no matter what I do, it complains at me:

```
Error when loading "--template": ./template

.../next/template/mui.template.ts:1
import { Template } from '@svgr/babel-plugin-transform-svg-component';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Option.parseArg (/.../.npm/_npx/0b534691f7d2b666/node_modules/@svgr/cli/dist/index.js:317:22)
    at handleOptionValue (/.../.npm/_npx/0b534691f7d2b666/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:545:24)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

At first I assumed this was because I was missing a `package.json` with `{"type": "module"}`, then I read some stuff about making it a `.mts` file, or perhaps some incorrect dependencies, but nothing I've tried seems to be working. How can I make this template file behave like a module?

---

**Update:** I know now that this is definitely something in @svgr (or my local?) that is forcing < ES6 import syntax. Rewriting with `require()` and `module.exports =` works. Just have to figure out how to force it to run in ES6 mode.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out and get it to work? Currently stuck on the exact same issue,  and struggling.

Comment: Noooo  I ended up sticking with old style and ignoring typescript errors.

Comment: Oof alright thanks

Answer (score 0):

But they are using `module.export` on their [Custom Component Template](https://react-svgr.com/docs/custom-templates/#custom-component-template) documentation page.

The one you've shown in OP is for using with webpack where it'll get transpiled.

---

May be changing `target` property of `rollup-plugin-esbuild` plugin in  https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/blob/main/build/rollup.config.js and rebuilding the cli part may help.

More info about rollup config: https://github.com/egoist/rollup-plugin-esbuild

Comment: Gave this a good shot but couldn't get it to work. Maybe the answer is that there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the build command to:

```
   "build": "tsc ./template.ts && npx @svgr/cli --typescript --memo --svg-props preserveAspectRatio='xMidYMid meet' --template ./template.js --out-dir dist -- icons"
```

Hoping I haven't misunderstood what you're asking - this helped fix the import issue for me. If so, apologies :)

Comment: It seems to terribly hate typescript, though I'm using the --typescript switch, and can load .ts files, I can't use any typescript-specific syntax like { something: string }

Comment: Ah, just did a ts-ignore on everything it complained about, but the import still doesn't work.